# while asp.net mvc4 upgrading jquery datepicker error

Tags: jquery, asp.net, asp.net-mvc-3, jquery-ui, asp.net-mvc-4

While I was upgrading my mvc3 project to mvc4, I met a problem about JQuery datepicker.

MVC3 project is using

- jquery-1.6.3
- jquery-ui-1.8.11

MVC4 project is using

- jquery-1.7.1
- jquery-ui-1.8.20

JQuery datepicker is working on mVC3 but an error occuring on mvc4.

[image]

My Model is this

```
public class Reservation
{
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public DateTime? Date { get; set; }
}
```

And my EditorTemplate is here.

```
model DateTime?

Html.TextBox("", Model.HasValue ? Model.Value.ToShortDateString() : string.Empty,  new { data_datepicker = true })
```

I applied the data attributes in model like this but not worked.

```
    [DataType(DataType.Date)]
    [DisplayFormat(DataFormatString = "{0:dd.mm.yyyy}")]
    public DateTime? Date { get; set; }
```

Answer (score 0):

May be your problem is jQuery references.Try to refer from **Google CDN** directly Likes below (these are the latest versions).

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.9.2/themes/base/jquery-ui.css"
            type="text/css" media="all" />
<script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.8.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.9.2/jquery-ui.min.js"></script>
```

I hope this will help to you.

Answer (score 0):

Try changing your model to

`[UIHint("DateTemplateYouAreUsing")]`
`public DateTime? Date { get; set; }`

and your editor template to
`$.validator.methods.date = function (value, element) {`
`!isNaN(Globalize.parseDate(value)); return this.optional(element) ||`
`}`

`@model DateTime`
`@Html.TextBox("", String.Format("{0:dd.MM.yyyy}", Model.ToShortDateString()),`
      `new { @class = "newdate" })`

and change your script to : 
 `$(document).ready(function () {`
         `$('.newdate').datepicker({ dateFormat: 'dd.mm.yy'});`
         `Globalize.culture('de-AT');`
       `});`

Dont forget to add
    
    
Download these file from https://github.com/jquery/globalize

Hope this works!!